# Checking for opposite directions in a datafile

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a dataset. First column is *ID numbers*, second column are *numbers*.

I'm looking to flag if the numbers in a given ID number go in opposite directions.

For example:

ID -- Number -- Checker
AA  : -10  - True
AA  : 11  - True
AB  : 10  - False
AB  : 11  - False
AC  : -5 - False
AC  : -5 - False
Because AB only has positive numbers, it flags as False. Because AA has both positive and negative numbers, it flags as True. Because AC only has negative numbers, it flags as False.

Comment: What do you mean by "if the numbers in a given ID number go in opposite directions"? That isn't clear at all (at least for me, even with the solution...)

Comment: Indeed - can you give us two examples, for "same and opposite directions" ?

Answer (score 0):

The way I managed to figure this out as I was typing out the problem was to use a helper column - ID & sign (number). Then `=isnumber(match(ID & - sign(number),helpercolumn))`